# My HTML Link Is Not Working

Tags: html, hyperlink, safari

I am new to HTML, and that's about to be very obvious, but I need some help on putting a simple link onto my website. The problem I'm experiencing is that my link when clicked on in Safari tries to pull from "file:///Users/kingwoody1/Desktop/Sample%20Website/â€œhttp://www.google.com/â€%C2%9D".

What am I missing? Why isn't it just going loading up google.com?

My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class=“headings”>
   <h1>Scott Woodson for President</h1>
    <p>A Man Of The People</p>
 </div>

 <div class=“options”>
   <ul>
     <li>
     <a href="http://www.google.com">Search for stuff</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have funky quotes which are probably breaking safari. Change all of the `“` and `”` to `"`:

`<div class=“headings”>` to `<div class="headings">`

and

`<div class=“options”>` to `<div class="options">`

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks for the help! Question now becomes, how do I use those quotes on a regular basis? I just copied and pasted yours from your comment into my code for this instance, but my keyboard defaults to the dumb kind of quotes. Any clue how to change that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I didn't even think that keyboards used those quotes by default. What editor do you use to write your code?

Answer (score 1):

This all looks good to me!
The only problem I can see in this code are the speach marks. Make sure to use the (") version for coding.
Not sure if this will help your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Close your `</html>` tag it may cause some problems.

By the way it works fine on Safari!

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine, but remember to close with 
    <./html>
, and use " as the funky quotes can cause problems in PHP (not sure about html).  Try using http://jsfiddle.net/ to test websites, and it allows you to make small changes without having to reopen the page.